# Merging multiple streams in java 8 with different types and length

Tags: java

How can I merge multiple streams in java 8 with different types and length

```
Stream<String> x = Stream.of("A", "B", "C");
Stream<Integer> y = Stream.of(3, 7);
Stream<Float> z = Stream.of(1.1f, 2.2f);
```

Expected result, is a steam that holds something like this:

```
A 3 1.1f
A 3 2.2f
A 7 1.1f
A 7 2.2f
B 3 1.1f
B 3 2.2f
B 7 1.1f
B 7 2.2f
C 3 1.1f
C 3 2.2f
C 7 1.1f
C 7 2.2f
```

Comment: Like a cartesian product? And what's the data type of `A 3 1.1f`?

Comment: That's a cartesian join, which requires iterating the value sets multiple times. Since a `Stream` can only be iterated once, start by gathering each stream into a `List`.

Comment: @ernest_k String, Integer, Float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to define some class that holds these 3 properties. Let's call it `Triplet`.

But since we have to stream over some of the sources of data multiple times, it's better to start with `List`s, not `Stream`s:

```
List<String> x = List.of("A", "B", "C");
List<Integer> y = List.of(3, 7);
List<Float> z = List.of(1.1f, 2.2f);
```

(If you must start with `Stream`s, you'll have to collect the second and third `Stream`s into `List`s first).

Now you can write:

```
Stream<Triplet> triplets =
    x.stream()
     .flatMap(a -> y.stream()
                    .flatMap (b -> z.stream()
                                    .map(c -> new Triplet(a,b,c))));
```

If you wish, you can make the `Triplet` class generic (and then produce a `Stream<Triplet<String,Integer,Float>>`).

Comment: Or use `new Object[] {a,b,c}`, or `a + " " + b + " " + c`, since we don't know what type OP wants the result to be.

Comment: @Andreas that's possible, but I find it ugly. I'd prefer to use a proper type (hence the suggested class).

Comment: @Eran we should use map over last stream, instead of flatMap. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original question used streams as input and those are not reusable, I want to add my version which converts the second and third streams to lists (with the performance penalty of list creation). If performance is an issue it would be best if you could have at least two of the streams as lists in the first place.

Also, if you want to use the `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9` library you have the Triple class which can hold the result.

```
    List<Integer> yList = y.collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Float> zList = z.collect(Collectors.toList());
    Stream<Triple<String, Integer, Float>> newStream =
            x.flatMap(a -> yList.stream()
                    .flatMap (b -> zList.stream()
                            .map(c -> Triple.of(a, b, c))));
    newStream.forEach(System.out::println);
```